# Amazon SES custom MAIL FROM Domain Not Sending Email Internally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I created a subdomain sesmail.xxxx.com using Cpanel where xxxx is my domain.

Sets it as the MAIL FROM Domain for Amazon SES, added the MX and TXT entry to my DNS Zone. Amazon SES verified it successfully.

I could send and receive emails to *external* domains such as gmail, yahoo and such. **HOWEVER**, I could not send emails to my own domain.

Turned on the notification and I found emails bounced with this error -

```
    Reporting-MTA: dsn; a4-21.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com

    Action: failed
    Final-Recipient: rfc822; david@xxxx.com
    Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-Verification failed for <01020172adb3b9ee-f8bc1443-9d2d-40b6-b9cc-6f4c388cd8b8-000000@sesmail.xxxx.com>
     550-No Such User Here"
     550 Sender verify failed
    Status: 5.3.0
```

Externally I could send and receive without problems. Internally I get this error when I send emails to myself. Removing the MAIL FROM Domain resolved the problem but that defeats the obvious purpose of using one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Kinda solved the problem. If anyone come across this problem, it is due to your domain/server MX not using any AWS service. You _can't_ use your own server MX for this MAIL FROM to work. Correct me if I'm wrong. 

What I did was use the Workmail, verified my domain with it and SES will automatically create Identity Policies to use with it. Created the email accounts needed and I was able to use the MAIL FROM domain.

Comment: So you were using sesmail.domain.com as sending & mail from domain? If so the ses mail from docs says this "The MAIL FROM domain shouldn't be a domain that you send email from. If you have to use the MAIL FROM domain in a From address, either disable email feedback forwarding and receive your bounces through Amazon SNS notifications, or ensure that your MAIL FROM domain is not the destination for feedback forwarding. To determine the destination of email forwarding feedback, see Email feedback forwarding destination." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html

Comment: No, the sending was from the root/mail. To satisfy the MAIL FROM, I created a subdomain sesmail. That won't work unless you could somehow configure sesmail on your server to work with SES.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently. And it was not a problem in the DNS registers. AWS has a Suppression list that is used when the emails bounces. So, maybe before the DNS where completly configured, you tried to send emails with same domains, and AWS send these mails to that supression list.

You can always check in AWS SES, this list in case you require.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda solved the problem. If anyone come across this problem, it is due to your domain/server MX not using any AWS service. You can't use your own server MX for this MAIL FROM to work. Correct me if I'm wrong. What I did was use the Workmail, verified my domain with it and SES will automatically create Identity Policies to use with it. Created the email accounts needed and I was able to use the MAIL FROM domain.